# Specify file directory in a program that will be installed on different machines?

Tags: c#, advanced-installer

I am creating my first installer (using Advanced Installer) for my program and I am wondering how best to specify the directory of files I will need to access in my program.

The program could be run on different machines that won't necessarily have the same folder names.

Currently I am doing;

```
 string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
 this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file://C:/Users/Test/Downloads/SerialPort/SerialPort/SerialPort/shrews.html", curDir));
```

For the installer, I am creating the necessary folder at [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName]

What would be the best way to reference files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By not referencing them but construct the reference.

Check the SpecialFolders enumeration - you can get the location of any known folder.

If you are afraid of the userchanging the location.... (and advanced installer is not good, try using WIX).... then ahve the installer write the path into a registry key that you then read.

**UPDATE**: Advanced Installer can also write the install path in the registry or in a settings file, no matter if the user changes the default install path or not.

The installation path is stored in the public property APPDIR, so you just need to refer this property when defining the registry.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't think about the special folders.

Comment: I've just seen your notice and I have edited my code accordingly. It's much better that it now looks in the registry for the install directory. Thank you again.